# mysql result need to my example

Tags: mysql

I have restaurant table.
I need to show first "open restaurants" & then closed restaurants result and also I searched zipcode is 2600. so fisrt list zipcode 2600 & then open restaurants then other zipcode of open restaurant. Then 2600 of closed restaurant then other zipcode of closed restaurant.

```
restid  resname Zipcode status
    1   Res1    2600    Open
    2   Res2    2500    Closed
    3   Res3    3600    Closed
    4   Res4    2600    Open
    5   Res5    2500    Closed
    6   Res6    2600    Open
    7   Res7    3600    Open
    8   Res8    3600    Open
    9   Res9    2500    Closed
    10  Res10   2600    Closed
```

I need the result like...

```
restid  resname zipcode status
    1   Res1    2600    Open
    2   Res4    2600    Open
    3   Res6    2600    Open
    4   Res7    3600    Open
    5   Res8    3600    Open
    6   Res2    2500    Closed
    7   Res3    3600    Closed
    8   Res5    2500    Closed
    9   Res9    2500    Closed
    10  Res10   2600    Closed
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you change the `restid`?  As for the rest of the question:  `order by status desc`.

Comment: If I understand it right it seems more like a series of unions with the order by mentioned by @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1):

```
select restid,resname,zipcode,status from sometable order by statys desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following solution :-

```
SELECT restid,resname,zipcode,status FROM restaurant WHERE zipcode = 2600 ORDER BY status DESC;
```

It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query for your desired output.

```
select * from restaurant WHERE zipcode = 2600  order by status desc
```